# How to enable curl on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

How to enable cURL on Wordpress.

I have install cURL on my server and I have also enabled in PHP.ini file(removed ; before extension) but still I'm getting error like cURL not available.

**cURL version on server**

```
 curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4     libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3  Release-Date: 2018-01-24  Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb     smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp   Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

**Site Health Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: The curl version shows a bash curl version, `curl --version`. Wordpress searches for the [php-curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension, did you installed it? Something like `apt-get install php-curl`?

Comment: Yes.I have installed that too.

Comment: Can you confirm the right version has been installed (The version Wordpress uses?) You can check the installed php modules with `php -m`

Comment: [PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: Did you've restarted the httpserver? Do you have multiple php versions installed on the machine?

Comment: yes.I have multiple php version also I have resorted server `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Ahh, in that case the output of `php-m` is probably showing the 'other' php version, not the one wordpress uses. You should check the wordpress config to see witch php version is used, then install that curl extension: eg: `apt-get install php7.2-curl`.

Comment: now it works :)

Comment: Great! Do you want me to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your php version `php -version`
2. Install the same-version php-curl:
   `sudo apt install php7.4-curl` (or whatever version you have)
3. Restart the server so Wordpress sees it (this is what fixed my problem).